# Video not covering the whole screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

I want my video to cover the entire screen but it seems to cover only half of the screen as follows
[image]

I have styled the video component as follows:

```
 <Video
                source={{uri: this.state.video}}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  alignItems: 'stretch',
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  height: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                }}
                resizeMode="cover"
                repeat={true}
              />
```

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this behavior and where am I going wrong?
Any help would be useful.

Comment: Why is height set as width value? `height: Dimensions.get('window').width,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow giving a height has solved the mentioned issue like follows:

```
  <Video
                source={{uri: this.state.video}}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  alignItems: 'stretch',
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  height: "90%",
                }}
                resizeMode="cover"
                repeat={true}
          
              />
```